# What is Mocha test case for having caught a TypeError from an async function?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, browser, mocha.js

I have the following function in `something.js`, a browser script.

```
async function somethingFunction(value) {
  try {

//Lots of lovely code manipulating 'value', 
//an improper assignment here by passing 'undefined' 
//to value argument of function would cause a TypeError
//When trying to access property of value (cannot access .test of undefined)

    let somethingVar = value.test;

    return somethingVar;
    
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error();
  }
}
```

And I've written as test as such:

```
describe(`#somethingFunction()`, async function () {
  context(`Passing undefined as value parameter should be caught be try catch block`, function () {
    it(`Should return error (TypeError)`, async function () {
      expect(async function () {
        await somethingFunction(undefined);
      }).to.throw(TypeError);
    });
  });
});
```

On this test, Mocha give:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw 'TypeError'
```

But passing `undefined` to this function does in fact cause a error - A TypeError!

Are TypeErrors caught? How would Mocha test this?

Tl;dr - How do I catch TypeErrors and get Mocha to test for them?

Comment: Your `somethingFunction` cannot throw a `TypeError`, only an `Error`.

Comment: Ok - But it does throw TypeError.....

Comment: If you want it to throw a `TypeError`, remove the try-catch block. Otherwise, it will throw a `new Error` instead (at least, that is what your code shows).

Comment: However it doesn't throw `new Error`... it definitely throws TypeError. I've adjusted the code slightly to make it more clear.  `let somethingElse = $(value).val();` creates `TypeError: $ is not a function` in the browser console

Comment: The line `throw new Error();` in your catch block overrides whatever error is thrown in the try block. Really, I can only give you some hints, but I can't teach you how to debug in the browser.